# popover plugin from bootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my problem : i'm lvl 0 in javascript and jquery. (i developp webapps with GWT so i don't have to write js)

I would like to use the [popover plugin from bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) but i don't know how, even if it seems simple.

Here's what i have :

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <a id="mylink" data-content="my txt" data-original-title="my title"> lol </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myLink").popover();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And that doesn't do anything.

Should i use "$(document).ready()" ? Am i missing options ? I seen someone add this method call :

```
.mouseenter(function(e) { $(this).popover('show'); });
```

But that doesn't change either.

I know this is real noob stuff, but i'm really lost.

Thanks :)

Comment: your start body tag is messed up....

Comment: i'd also suggest using your browsers dev tools to see if there's an error.

Comment: Have a peek at [this jQuery document-ready tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) if you want to know what it's about.

Comment: If you're interacting with a DOM element, you should be using document ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Bootstrap requires a fairly new version of jquery. So change the jquery reference to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and change `$('#myLink')` to `$('#mylink')`.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML should contain the following to get the popover to work:

This code waits for the page to load, and then enables popover on your link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('#mylink').popover();
    });
<script>
```

Include jquery and popover javascript.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
```